# How to visualise an FGR object in RStudio

Tags: r, graph, survival-analysis

I am doing a Fine-Gray regression using the riskregression package in R and am having trouble visualizing my data once my analysis is complete. I have tried to use the GGally package to get a forest plot of the coefficients and the CIs but the error message I am getting is

"Error: Error: No tidy method for objects of class FGR"

Wondering is there a way to directly visualise FGR objects? Or convert them to another class that is easy to visualise or convert to academic looking tables?

GGally just a package I have used before that worked well on a different project but would be happy to use any package that works,

Many thanks, reprex below

```
df <- data.frame(
  time_at_risk = c(1,2,3,4,5),
  outcome = c(0,1,0,1,1),
  predictor = c(1,1,0,2,3))

library(cmprsk)
library(riskRegression)
library(GGally)
library(prodlim)


model <- FGR(Hist(time_at_risk, outcome) ~ predictor,
            data = df) 

summary(model)

ggcoef_model(model)
```

Comment: Is there a summary method? Many regression object have a coefficient element in the list returned by a ‘summary’ call.

Comment: You can print and summary the FGR object and get the output and the coefficients so that works. Then my job is to try and get that data into a publishable format without having manually type everything out, like what you can do with gtsummary etc.

Comment: If you are looking for tested code, then you first need a library call and then code that results in an object for demonstration.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean, I have an object already from my analysis. It just happens that that object is of class "FGR" which is a class I can't do anything with. To get that object I used the FGR command from the package riskregression

Comment: Code. Show the code!

Comment: Sometimes I'm willing to do the digging around and searching and building test cases for vague questions that lack any code and fail to mention needed packages to load, but this time I'm still waiting. Run a clean session; load packages needed (including all the tidyverse stuff), and create objects (perhaps using code from help pages. And post the code. Then you can get effort from us. Not before.